# Using JTextFields, JButtons and JLabels on JFrame with ActionListener and if-else Statement Jbutton Does Not Work

Tags: java

I am new to Java and am trying to do my first project. The code below has a button that when clicked, nothing happens. I am working on Eclipse and there are no exceptions thrown.

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MTV extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    public JTextField kutucuk1, kutucuk2, kutu3;
    public JLabel kutu1, kutu2;
    public JButton buton1;
    int yas, motorhacmi;

    public MTV() {      
        setLayout(new GridLayout (3,3));
        kutu1 = new JLabel("Aracınızın yası");
        kutucuk1 = new JTextField(yas);
        kutu2 = new JLabel("Aracınızın Motor Hacmi");
        kutucuk2 = new JTextField(motorhacmi);
        buton1 = new JButton("Hesapla");
        kutu3 = new JTextField();


        setTitle("MTV Hesaplama");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(600, 500);
        setVisible(true);

        add(kutu1);
        add(kutucuk1);
        add(kutu2);
        add(kutucuk2);
        add(buton1);
        add(kutu3); 
        buton1.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        yas = Integer.parseInt(kutucuk1.getText().toString());
        motorhacmi = Integer.parseInt(kutucuk2.getText().toString());

        if (motorhacmi <= 1300 && (yas <=3 && yas >=1)) {               
            kutu3.setText("Ödenecek vergi 743");
        }           
        else if ((motorhacmi > 1300 && motorhacmi <= 1600) && (yas <=3 && yas >=1)) {                           
            kutu3.setText("Ödenecek vergi 1294");               
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MTV mtv = new MTV();
    }
}
```

Comment: Try adding a few traces to see what happens within your if-else clause.

Comment: Try some debugging add a System.out.println in your action perform method.

Answer (score 0):

try this link [Eclipse Gui](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/desktop-java/ide/eclipse/eclipse-window-builder-tutorial-gui-creation/)   if you are using eclipse then instead of creating  the text Fields and  buttons and all this components you   will only drag and drop and the code is already written when  you select and component

Comment: This is great! Thank you very much.

Comment: i hope it helped

Answer (score 0):

Or add sizes to the JTextFields and also change the placement of all the elements to before the pane creation:

```
add(kutu1);
add(kutucuk1);
add(kutu2);
add(kutucuk2);
add(buton1);
add(kutu3); 
buton1.addActionListener(this);
setTitle("MTV Hesaplama");
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
setSize(600, 500);
setVisible(true);
```