# How to add an Image to a JFrame

Tags: java, image, swing, jframe, jlabel

I'm trying to add an image to a `JFrame` and set its location, I don't know why it just does not add into it, maybe I don't understand how the `JFrame` class works since a normal text `JLabel` adds into the `JFrame` simply without any trouble and a `JLabel` containing an image simply does not add in.

I would appreciate if someone would explain the error in the code, and maybe even give me a short explanation of why my way does not work. Thanks!

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Walk {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Study");
        f.setSize(3000,1000);
        f.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.white);
        f.getContentPane().add(new JLabel("test", JLabel.CENTER) );
        JLabel l = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\leguy\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Stuff\\stillsp"));
        l.setBounds(100, 100, 100, 100);
        l.setVisible(true);
        f.add(l);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: To start with; `C:\\Users\\leguy\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Stuff\\stillsp` looks suspicious.  Second, `BorderLayout` will only manage a single component at each of it's five available locations, you've got two at `CENTER`.  Third, Swing components are visible by default. Fourth, `setBounds` is unlikely to have much affect in this situation.  I'd recommend using `ImageIO.read` over `ImageIcon` to load the image, `ImageIO` will at least throw an exception when the image can't be loaded

Answer (score 0):

1. are you using a gui class or you are writing its code into a main class
   what is in your code is that you are writing its code   so easy way is to just drag and drop  try this link for normal jframes gui  [eclipse gui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51348991/9007554)

about the picture into jframe is easy one all what you have to do is 
1. create a  label by setting its size as you want on the jframe by dragging and dropping only 
2. follow the pictures [image]

3. then you browser for your picture you want [image]
4. select the picture  and its done
   [image]

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the path to your image is valid. All I did was point to a valid image on my PC and the code practically worked. There were a few things added and organized below.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Walk {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() { // Safety first...
            @Override
            public void run() {
                String path = "C:\\Path\\To\\Image.png"; // Make sure it's correct
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Study");
                JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(path));

                frame.setSize(3000, 1000);
                frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.white);
                frame.getContentPane().add(new JLabel("test", JLabel.CENTER));

                label.setBounds(100, 100, 100, 100);
                label.setVisible(true);

                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(label);
                frame.pack(); // Pack the frame's components.
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

To make sure both labels show up, provide a layout and add them accordingly.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Walk {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                String path         = "C:\\Path\\To\\Image.png"; // Make sure it's correct
                JFrame frame        = new JFrame("Study");
                Container container = frame.getContentPane();
                JLabel imageLbl     = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(path));
                JLabel textLbl      = new JLabel("test");

                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.setSize(3000, 1000);

                imageLbl.setBounds(100, 100, 100, 100);
                imageLbl.setVisible(true);

                container.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                container.add(textLbl, BorderLayout.NORTH);
                container.add(imageLbl, BorderLayout.CENTER);

                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```